# Hash router is not staying on same page when refreshing

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to hash router and using it in my project ( because backend use asp.net and without it, refreshing won't work ). So after I used it, refreshing works. But I notice whenever I refresh the page let's say I am on `http://localhost:3000/#/assets/list-table/list-new-form`, it doesn't stay on the same `../list-new-form` when I refresh but instead to dashboard `#/dashboard`. Here is how I added hash router into my project

```
..
 <React.Suspense fallback={<LayoutSplashScreen />}>
          <HashRouter
            basename={basename}
          >
         
            <MaterialThemeProvider>
              <I18nProvider>
                <Routes />
              </I18nProvider>
            </MaterialThemeProvider>
         
          </HashRouter>
  </React.Suspense>
..
```

In this case, I am using metronic theme and `basename` is empty string when I console log in `index.js`, I am wondering I need to insert something into `basename` (/ or dashboard) or am I missing something here ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BrowserRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter), as same as HashRouter.
using BrowserRouter your links would be like `http://localhost:3000/assets/list-table/list-new-form` (without `#` in url). So whenever you refresh it will stay on same page.

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <MaterialThemeProvider>
       <I18nProvider>
          <Routes />
       </I18nProvider>
    </MaterialThemeProvider>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Please upvote and accept my answer if it solves your issue

Comment: I can't use `BrowserRouter` because refreshing won't work with `BrowserRouter`. That's why I changed to `HashRouter` to add hash (#) in url. I already had 
  `<BrowserRouter basename={basename}>` and I deleted it. Is there a way to achive it with `HashRouter`

Comment: @KaungKhantZaw you cannot achieved this with `HashRouter`